# Maximum rows to partially distinguish all the columns

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, co.combinatorics

This is a problem I met in my work. I thought about it for about two weeks, no result. I don't know whether it has been studied before by others?

**Problem Description**: Given an $m\times n$ matrix $M$ with entries valued 0 or 1. Let $r_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ row,
$c_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ column and $t_{ij}$ denote the entry in the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column. Find a $k \times n$ submatrix $A$ of $M$, such that in $A$
\begin{equation}
\forall_{r_i}{ \exists_{c_a,c_b}{ \forall_{r_j \ne r_i}{\left(  t_{ia} \ne t_{ib} \land t_{ja} = t_{jb} \right) } } }.
\end{equation}
$k$ is the parameter

The selected rows satisfy the following condition: For each row $r_i$, there exist two columns $c_a, c_b$, such that entries of the two columns at row $i$ are different, and at the remaining rows are the same.

Could someone give me **any reference for it**, if it has been studied before ? Thank you very much.

At first, I thought it was a special case of Minimum Test Set problem, however, it turns out not.

Comment: OK. It is not copied from some article, actually, I am asking for reference for this problem. It is copied from my draft.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, only an extended comment on a possible transformation of the problem (hope it is correct :-).

Each row can be "mapped" to a $n \times (n-1) / 2$ *"extended"* row. Each element of the extended row represents a pair of elements in the original row and is set to 1 if the two elements are different, set to 0 if the two elements are the same.

For example:

```
row_i = 10011  
        ^1100   (*)
         ^011   
          ^11
           ^0

extended_row_i = 1100 011 11 0

(*) note that in building the extended row, when the current bit (marked with ^)
is 0, the remaining bits are just copied and when the current bit is 1 the
remaining bits are inverted
```

We can extend each row and obtain an *"extended" matrix*. For example the matrix:

```
10011
01101
00011
```

Becomes:

```
1100 011 11 0
1101 010 10 1
0011 011 11 0
```

And the original problem reduces to find a submatrix of the *"extended" matrix* with exactly one 1 in each column.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness. I think the transformation is correct. Your transferred( extended ) matrix problem seems like NP-complete. So it does not justifies the original problem is NP-complete. If the extended matrix problem is in P, then the original problem got solved. Actually, I did a similar transformation before I ask, transferring a $n\times m$ input matrix to a $n \times (m-1)*m/2$ matrix, with each entry is a subset of indicies of rows. However, I cannot prove my transferred problem is NP-hard or polynomially solvable.